# declaringn a variable in java class (private,static,final)

Tags: java, static, private

There are many discussions about `static` and `final` variables in Java. 
I really want to know the differences between the following declarations. Seems to be confusing

```
public class foo() {
    private static final int a;
    private static int b;
    private final int c;
    private int d;
    public static final int e;
    public static int f;
    public final int g;
    public int h;
}
```

Which one can be modified/accessed inside/outside of the class?

P.S: The question in [In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-default-public-protected-and-private) is a larger scope. Mine is focusing on some confusing points!

Comment: `private` means it is private to that class and not accessible outside that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`private` means it can be accessed only by instances of class `foo`.

`public` means it can be accessed from any object owning a reference to an instance of Class `foo`.

`static` means it belongs to the class and thus, it's shared by all `foo` instances.

`final` means it can't change its initial value.

`final` properties can't be modified once initialized. `static` properties can be modified, but remember that the new value is shared by all instances. `private` properties can be modified only by a `foo` instance itself.

This means that a `static final` property that: can't be modified; is shared by all instances.

Answer (score 2):

```
private static final int a; // accessed only         / inside only
private static       int b; // accessed and modified / inside only
private        final int c; // accessed only         / inside only
private              int d; // accessed and modified / inside only
public  static final int e; // accessed only         / inside and outside
public  static       int f; // accessed and modified / inside and outside
public         final int g; // accessed only         / inside and outside
public               int h; // accessed and modified / inside and outside
```

As you can see:

- `static` has no effect here whatsoever
- `final` reduces `accessed and modified` to `accessed only`
- `private`/`public` determines `inside only` / `inside and outside`

Comment: You probably want to qualify your assertion that "static has no effect here whatsoever" to clarify that you mean it has no effect as far as accessibility is concerned. It does, of course have an effect in other ways.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou: Yes, I did put some thought into that immediately after posting my answer. However, I think that the word `here` implies it, and in addition to that (even more persuasive) - it makes no sense for a keyword to have no effect whatsoever, so I think it's pretty obvious that "no effect" is in the context of the question... What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

`public` attributes can be accessed from any class.

`private` attributes can be accessed just in the class where it's declared. (This is why we need to include getters and setters for example in the other classes to retrieve private vars)

`final` attributes cannot be modified and set to a different value.

`static` attributes are accessed in the class itself and in its instances.

Answer (score 0):

In context of the class identifiers the statements have meaning as explained below:
firstly `private` and `public` keywords are access signifiers, which means all members with `private` keyword are only visible in the scope of the class they are declared. All the members with `public` keyword are visible outside the scope of the class.

e.g

```
class foo{
      public int myVar;
      private int myBar;
}
```

Now if you instantiate `foo'

```
foo f = new foo();
f.myVar // is valid
f.myBar // is invalid and generates compile time error.
```

`static` keyword signifies that the allocation of the identifier is common for all instances of the class, so this identifier is allocated at the time when compiler encounters type definition for first time. Since, the type allocation for any class happens only once, there is only one instance of the static field maintained which can be accessed across all objects of this class.

`final` keyword signifies (in context of identifiers), that these identifiers can be initialised once and are then closed for any modification.
(in context of methods it means that the method cannot be overridden by the derived classes).

Now coming back to your question, following statements will mean:

```
private static final int a; 
// 'a' has scope local to the class and its value is accessible through Type
// and shared across all instances of that type and its value cannot be
// changed once initialised. 
private static int b;
// 'b' has scope local to the class and its value is accessible through Type
// and shared across all instances of that type.
private final int c;
// 'c' has scope local to the class and its value cannot be changed once 
// initialised.
private int d;
// 'd' has scope local to the class
public static final int e;
// 'e' has scope beyond the class, it can be accessed outside the class 
// through an instance of this class and its value is accessible through
// Type and shared across all instances of that type 
// and its value cannot be changed once initialised. 
public static int f;
// 'f' has scope beyond the class, it can be accessed outside the class and   
// value is accessible through Type and shared across all instances of that
// type
public final int g;
// 'g' has scope beyond the class, it can be accessed outside the class
// through an instance of this class 
// and its value cannot be changed once initialised.
public int h;
// 'h' has scope beyond the class, it can be accessed outside the class
// through an instance of this class
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`public`- A class, member method, constructor, interface etc declared public can be accessed from any other class.we can say that it have global access.

`private`-Member Methods, memeber Variables and Constructors that are declared private can only be accessed within the declared class itself.Variables that are declared private can be accessed outside the class if public getter methods are present in the class.

`final`- final will ensure that the field is a constant and can't be changed

`static`-it is associated with the type and not with the instances. i.e. only one copy of the field will be present for all the objects and not individual copy for each object.means a single copy of field will be shared among all the object of that class

`static final`-all instances of that class will share the same value and can't be modified after first initialization.

Answer (score -2):

1. `private` means it can not be seen outside of class.
2. `static` means that the variable is associated with the class, not the object.  This means that for any object, its static variables will be shared by all objects of the same class. [(more information)](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-for-beginners-static-variables-what-are-they.html)
3. `final` means that once you assign a value to the variable, you cannot reassign it.

From outside the class you can only access `public` variables, but you can't modify the `final` ones.